# Posting to sentry is returning an event ID, but it isn't showing in my issues

Tags: javascript, sentry

I'm trying to log a custom message to Sentry and I'm doing it using

`Sentry.captureMessage("This is a test");`

When this function is executed on my application I can see in the Dev Tools Network tab that the request is executed successfully:

[image: 200 response for sentry request]

And it also returns an event ID:

`{"id":"b1db5de34d6048b38f76077ed1315fe9"}`

The problem is that when I check the issues tab on the Sentry project, the message is nowhere to be found. There are other issues for the application but these are things like unhandled errors.

Are there some steps I need to follow to log messages from the `captureMessage` function? Can I just immediately go to the event since I have the event ID?

Answer (score 1):

After a usually-short delay, you can get to the related issue in sentry by visiting a URL like: f"https://sentry.io/{organization_slug}/{project_slug}/events/{event_id}".

Comment: Is there an updated URL? This does not seem to work

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw https://${org_slug}.sentry.io/issues/?query=${event_id}/